# How does a 4 pin RGB connector work without ground?

Tags: optoelectronics

The question is in title. Why there is no ground pin on the 12V RGB header? The 5V ARG header which uses only 3 pins has a ground.

How does it work without a ground?

[image]

Comment: Who says you have to drive the RGB lines high? ;) Drive them low and you have your ground.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is how it looks on the driver end. Whatever channel you want to drive, the R, G and/or B becomes ground with the help of a transistor, completing the circuit and allowing current to flow.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRrrNk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT: Added colors for clarity.

Comment: Good answer.  Note that this configuration is an example of low-side switching, where the switching device (transistors in this case) are in the return, or low-side path of the power flow.

Comment: @SteveSh Unless someone invents a new type of transistor with majority carrier yet controlled by negative gate voltage (depletion MOSFET comes close if they would be off with 0 V Vgs), we will have low side switching for the foreseeable future.

Comment: @winny Isn't that just a P-channel FET?

Comment: @Hearth P-channel is minority carrier. Hence 3 times as expensive for the same Vds and RdsON.

Comment: @winny No, p-channel devices are still majority carrier devices. The fact that holes have lower mobility in silicon doesn't make them minority carriers--it's the doping that determines that, and the doping in p-channel devices makes holes the majority carrier. Just like the doping in n-channel devices makes electrons the majority carrier there.

Comment: @Hearth All those years at a university… Thanks for the correction. So it’s all about the mobility, not if the holes and electrons are in majority or minority.

Comment: @winny Yes. Minority carriers are only involved in conduction in any significant way in BJTs, diodes, and thyristors; MOSFETs, JFETs, and HEMTs are majority-carrier devices.

Comment: @Hearth You learn something every day.

Answer (score 15):

But there is a ground. Or actually, three grounds.

The three RGB wires are the grounds for the three LED colours.

The three colours just share a single +12V supply wire.

Comment: The RGB wires are the cathodes. They're grounded through the controller. (I know you know. You just didn't explain it well.)

Answer (score 6):

The anodes of all LEDs are connected to the 5V/12V. The cathodes of the LEDs go to the R, G, and B pins of the connector.
The controlling device then connects the pins to ground to make the respective color light up.

Comment: The 5 V version is the addressable type. The connector shows +5, D, nc, GND.

Answer (score 5):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fKprDk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A manually switched controller for an RGB LED strip.*

Closing the R, G or B switches will ground the last cathode of each string of R, G or B LEDs and cause them to light up. The switches can be replaced by transistors and these can be controlled by a microcontroller.

> How does a 4 pin RGB connector work without ground?

The ground is provided by the control circuit.